# Usage of the words "wooden" and "wood"

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence

> He should get a wooden table, not a plastic one

why cannot "wooden" be replaced by the word "wood"?

Comment: *wood* can be used as an adjective or a noun. If you say "wood table" then *wood* functions as an adjective.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it couldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why it can't in this context.  Both "wood" and "wooden" can mean "made from wood".

> Use the **wooden/wood** spoon to stir the soup, as that won't damage the pot.

However these words are not interchangeable.  "Wooden" refers specifically to those things which are *manufactured* from wood (or which metaphorically appear to have been made from wood).

> It's an old **wooden** doll that has been in my family for centuries.

"Wood" can mean the same, or it can refer to the base or source of the thing:

> [How to stoke a **wood** fire stove](https://www.hunker.com/13408439/how-to-stoke-a-wood-fire)
>
> Our real **wood** paper is made from actual very thin **wood** veneer and a paper backing.

Unfortunately, a lot of this seems to be idiomatic.  For example, both "wood board" and "wooden board" are natural ways to describe the same thing, but "wooden paper" sounds different from "wood paper".